# delete button on top right

Tags: html, css

What I am trying to do is show the delete icon when the user hover an image. The hovering part is working but the problem is I can't position the x button to the top right corner of the image.

html

```
<div class="photos">
    <div id="images">
        <a href=# data-lightbox="roadtrip">
            <img class=img width=100 height=100 alt='Unable to View' src=""></a>

        <a href="#" class="del_photo" id=""><img src="images/icon_del.gif" border="0" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#images {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px
}

.del_photo {
    display: inline-block;
    float:right;
    margin:5px 5px 0 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jHG9v/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier to use a relative position for your container and position the close button absolute (see http://jsfiddle.net/jHG9v/1/):

```
#images {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.del_photo {
    display: inline-block;
    float:right;
    margin:5px 5px 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: altrough I was 9 seconds sooner, +1 on your question for more content.

Answer (score 3):

Use `position:relative;` and `position:absolute;` as in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Y75va/

*edit*

See @Alexander Kludt anwser for code + more info.

Comment: well that was in exactly the same second, please consider adding code to your post next time

Comment: Will do next time, sir.

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS to this.

```
#images {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px
    position: relative
}

.del_photo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jHG9v/5/)

CSS

```
#images {

    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative
}

.del_photo {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    float:right;
    margin:5px 5px 0 0;
}
```